# NextJS static site 404 request for feed.rss.json

Tags: next.js

I rewrote my blog in nextjs, built with output: "export". I set it up to statically create a feed.rss file with a Link set to prefetch={false}. After deploying, the site is making an ajax request to /_next/data/7Ri77b0woPvlubzepQHO7/feed.rss.json?id=feed.rss which is returning a 404.

I can't figure out why nextjs is making this request. I understand it does prefetching, so I set prefetch to false, but it still makes the request.  I also don't really understand why this feed.rss.json 404s when the other page's .json requests succeed.

The deployed site is at https://www.kevinberridge.com and the source code is at https://github.com/kberridge/kwblog.